# How to retrieve Database data from selecting rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

How do I actually retrieve the Primary Key (model.ID) of the selected row from my table. And i want to make same cases if a single row is selected button A B C are enabled but if multiple rows are selected only button c is enabled , a and b will be disabled.
I posted my coding below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#LineTables').DataTable();

    $('#LineTables tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });
    });
});

<table id="LineTables" class="display dataTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductionOrderNumber)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesOrder.Product.ProductGroup.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesOrder.Product.ProductName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesOrder.Product.Pole)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesOrder.Product.Amperage)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesOrder.SalesOrderType1.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesOrder.Market)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductionOrderStatu.Name)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SalesOrder.SalesOrderNumber)</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductionOrderNumber)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesOrder.Product.ProductGroup.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesOrder.Product.ProductName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesOrder.Product.Pole)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesOrder.Product.Amperage)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesOrder.SalesOrderType1.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesOrder.Market)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductionOrderStatu.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SalesOrder.SalesOrderNumber)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("New Barcode", "Barcode", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "barcode btnic btnicon" })
            </td>
        </tr>
        } </tbody>

</table>
@Html.ActionLink("A", "Index", "A", .......... , new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-ms" })
@Html.ActionLink("B", "Index", "B", .......... , new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-ms" })
@Html.ActionLink("C", "Index", "C", .......... , new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-ms" })
```

Comment: Where are you wanting to retrieve the ID? in the row click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based comments above:

Firstly you cant use `@Html.ActionLink(..)` for the 'buttons (these are rendered on the server side and you dont know the selected ID at that point) - use a html `<button id="edit">Edit</button>`. In the row.click function, test the number of selected rows and enable/disable the buttons as required

```
var selectedRows = $(this).closest('tbody').children('tr')
  .filter('.selected').length;
if (selectedRows = 1) {
  // enable edit and details buttons
} else {
  // disable edit and details buttons
}
```

Then in the click events for each button (edit button shown)

```
$('#edit').click(function() {
  var ID = $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val(); // as per first answer 
  window.location.href = '/yourController/edit/' + ID;
  return false;
});
```

The delete button will be a little more complicated - one way would be to loop the selected rows, get the ID and use AJAX to post the ID to your 'Delete' action method, then in the success function, delete the row from your table, for example (not tested)

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Delete")"; // your delete action

$('#delete').click(function() {
  $('#LineTables').children('tbody').children('tr')
    .filter('.selected').each(function) {
    var row = $(this);
    var ID = row.find('input[type="hidden"]').val();
    $.post(url, { ID = ID }, function() {
      row.remove();
    });
```